# Rename a portion of multiple files

Tags: linux, rename, mv

Take a number of files named:

```
data_a_LT.fits
data_a_LT.coo
data_a_LT.ec
data_a_LT.grp
```

I want to replace all "a_LT" with "LT_A" such that I have:

```
data_LT_A.fits
data_LT_A.coo
data_LT_A.ec
data_LT_A.grp
```

How does one do this with one command.
Something like:

```
mv *a_LT* *LT_A*
```

Comment: Do you want one command, or a one-liner? Is a function ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [`rename`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) is available use this command:

```
rename 's/a_LT/LT_A/' *
```

Another approach with `awk`:

```
find -type f | awk -F'a_LT' '{printf "mv \"%s\" \"%sLT_A%s\"\n", $0, $1, $2}' | bash
```

Comment: The `rename` command varies depending on OS and distro. There is one that comes with `perl` and another that comes with `util-linux`.

Answer (score 3):

Using bash:

```
for file in *; do [[ -f "$file" ]] && mv "$file" "${file/a_LT/LT_A}"; done
data_LT_A.coo
data_LT_A.ec
data_LT_A.fits
data_LT_A.grp
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm used to using xargs:

```
ls -1 | sed 's/\(\(.*\)a_LT\(.*\)\)/\1 \2LT_A\3/' | xargs -n 2 mv
```

Comment: Those are three commands, the OP asked one command.

Comment: define "one command" ;-)

Comment: one command less: :-D

echo "ls -1 | sed 's/\(\(.*\)a_LT\(.*\)\)/\1 \2LT_A\3/' | xargs -n 2 mv" | sh

Answer (score 0):

rename might not work as expected in CentOS based systems.. In that case, you can download [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/files/perl/rename.pl.txt) script and copy it in your machine as $HOME/bin/rename.pl.

```
rename.pl 's/a_LT/LT_A/g' * -vn
```

will work as expected now..

It's better to run

```
rename.pl -n 's/a_LT/LT_A/g' *
```

before running the first command, as this will display the would be output without actually changing the names.

Comment: Why should he need to copy it to `/usr/bin`? It will be overwritten next time `util-linux` is upgraded.

Comment: Didn't think of it.. edited now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I went for the following which worked a treat.

```
rename 's/a_LT/LT_A/g' *
```

One liner, concise and easy to remember.